# Plain text to JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express

My application launches AWS ElasticBeanstalk environments on demand. These EB environments are automatically subscribed to an AWS SNS topic which sends messages to my applications webhook URL via HTTP POST.

The issue is that below is an example "message" object and the data is sent to the webhook in the form of plain text so there are instances of `\n` everywhere in the message which is of no use to me. I'd like wherever there is a break for there to be a new object which my application can clearly access (via Message.Timestamp, Message.Message, etc.)

```
Message: 'Timestamp: Fri Aug 21 22:25:23 UTC 2015\nMessage: Adding instance 'xxx' to your environment.\n\nEnvironment: xxx\nApplication: xxx\n\nEnvironment URL: xxx\nNotificationProcessId: xxx'
```

Is that possible...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sure**.  Just use some `RegExp` with a couple `.split()` methods and BAM.

```
var a = "Timestamp: Fri Aug 21 22:25:23 UTC 2015\nMessage: Adding instance 'xxx' to your environment.\n\nEnvironment: xxx\nApplication: xxx\n\nEnvironment URL: xxx\nNotificationProcessId: xxx";

// Break it up at the \n's
var b = a.split(/\n+/);

// I don't like using the same variable that I'm messing with, so let's make a new one.
var Message = {};

// Loop through, break each string where the ": " is, and assign key: value to Message.
b.forEach(function(str) {
  var data = str.split(/:\s/);

  // Get rid of whitespace in the object key.
  Message[data[0].replace(/\s/, "")] = data[1];
});

// See the results of each step.
console.log(a, b, "Message:", Message);
```

In your example there are instances of `\n` and some `\n\n` so this code will adapt to either (or more).

### [Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/wosotoqopo/edit?js,console)

Comment: This is perfect, man! I'm kind of a newb with regex... A small tweak is needed however as the Environment URL section of the message is coming through as: `'Environment URL': 'http',`

Comment: @leaksterrr guess if I wasn't lazy that wouldn't have been an issue lol but it's fixed now (assuming that's the only surprise character you expect to come through).  Demo changed also

Comment: Ah, sorry dude. I meant that the URL is actually being "cut off" and only coming through as 'http' rather than `http://environment-url`. I guess I should have been a bit more clear... It's late.

Comment: oh lol of course just gotta remove the `?` from the `var data ...`.  Fixed again.  And if that's the case you can also remove the change I made before it that removed whitespace if you want